# Unable to autowire 2 beans of same type but different names even after using qualifier

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am working on a spring-boot application and I have a configuration class in which i have defined 2 beans of same type but with different names and i am using that bean as parameter to a different bean, i am using qualifier to have different names but still i am not able to autowire the bean

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by jauharia on 6/28/2017.
 */
@Configuration
public class DbConfig {

    @Bean(name = "sourceJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate sourceJdbcTemple(@Qualifier("srcDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }


    @Bean(name = "srcDataSource")
    public DataSource sourceDataSource(Config config) {
        String driverClassName = config.getString("dbPullConfig.Database.Source.driver");
        String url = config.getString("dbPullConfig.Database.Source.url");
        String userName = config.getString("dbPullConfig.Database.Source.username");
        String password = config.getString("dbPullConfig.Database.Source.password");

        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(url);
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(userName);
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(password);

        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "destDataSource")
    public DataSource destinationDataSource(Config config) {
        String driverClassName = config.getString("dbPullConfig.Database.Destination.driver");
        String url = config.getString("dbPullConfig.Database.Destination.url");
        String userName = config.getString("dbPullConfig.Database.Destination.username");
        String password = config.getString("dbPullConfig.Database.Destination.password");

        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(url);
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(userName);
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(password);

        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "config")
    public Config config() {
        return ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("DbPullConfig.conf"));
    }
}
```

And i am getting the below error

```
parameter 0 of method sourceJdbcTemple in com.ambuj.risk.DbConfig required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - srcDataSource: defined by method 'sourceDataSource' in class path resource [com/ambuj/risk/DbConfig.class]
    - destDataSource: defined by method 'destinationDataSource' in class path resource [com/ambuj/risk/DbConfig.class]
```

pom is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>DbPull</artifactId>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase.jconnect</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconn4</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: use @primary annotation which is mostly used in your project

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? This looks correct. Note also that you can use the method call `sourceDataSource()` from within an `@Bean` method on the same configuration class, which may be good enough for your case.

Comment: @AmbujJauhari Can you include the import statements as well? The only case I can think of is that you are using Qualifier annotation from some other library say javax.inject.Qualifier.

Comment: @KalaiselvanA its a tool to copy data from 1 db to another and in most of the cases that we will have source and destination datasources.

Comment: @yaswanth added the import statements, i am using the 'org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier' annotation

Comment: @AmbujJauhari ok. I see DbConfig is annotated with Component annotation. Configuration annotation is the recommended way of using Bean annotations. Can you try doing that?

Comment: @yaswanth sorry i copy-pasted the wrong file, my bad, corrected it i am using Configuration only.

Comment: @AmbujJauhari did you try changing the name of the parameter to srcDataSource?

Comment: @yaswanth I tried @Qualifier("srcDataSource") DataSource srcDataSource but same error

Comment: @AmbujJauhari You can try calling that method directly like chrylis suggested. I think that's a workaround but can you try it out and see if it works?